# How to add heading to position using openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, geolocation, heading

I've seen the geolocation with tracking example in OL3, what it does is it rotates the view depending on the heading of the device.

I've done some research on the web and all what I've found does the same thing

**My question: is there a way to display the heading of the device without rotating the view ?**

Comment: you could have a look at https://github.com/itjope/ol3-my-location

Comment: @markgraeflerland thanks for the suggestion. I've checked on it, but I think it needs npm install, I forgot to say that I'm not using Node on my app